# Is there a working method for recreating a quicktime video resource fork?

Tags: macos, video, quicktime, hex-editor

A few years ago, I backed up a directory of family movies in quicktime format to my NAS. Unfortunately, only the data files went, and NOT the resource forks. Months later when I went to import those files to iMovie I found them unusable and the resource forks were long gone. Just my luck!

I've done a bit of poking around with HexEdit, and after a bit of toying with Dumpster, I've only managed to recover a few partial frames. I've tried creating new files in a similar format, but unfortunately I don't recall the frame size/rate. After pasting in a 'recreated' resource fork via HexEdit, in Dumpster I can view frame details, but I don't seem to be able to consistently edit them.

My question is, has anyone else been successful at doing this? I can't imagine this is a very unique problem. Short of creating a file with every possible frame dimension, and doing trial and error, is there an easier way to update the Quicktime atoms/containers? Or to discover the frame dimensions via details in HexEdit?

I've been picking at this for a few years now, coming back to it every 6 months or so for a fresh try, new google searches.

Comment: I didn't know QT used resource forks to store additional (possibly important) video information. Do you know what exactly is stored in there? How exactly are they unusable? It might be possible to just extract the video/audio bitstreams and re-wrap them again using third party tools.

Comment: I don't believe the current quicktime spec does. But these were created back when .mov was the default video format. If I remember correctly, the files were created in 2004. This was back when resource forks held the file details separate from the video data, until you re-exported as a 'self-contained' movie. Link to the old-style QTFF: 

https://developer.apple.com/standards/qtff-2001.pdf

Comment: Oh, so it's basically the `moov` atom that's pushed into the data fork and now missing? This might be beyond my knowledge, but you *could* for example try to run `ffmpeg -i -input.mov -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mov` and see if it's able to recreate the atom.

Comment: I don't suspect it will be that easy, but I will give this a shot tonight. Problem is, with no resource fork, there is no atom, just data. So ffmpeg will not find the necessary details to pick out the audio and video tracks. I can pick out some of those details in HexEdit, but I don't believe ffmpeg will be able to.

Comment: I know this is a tricky issue. You probably already know more about this stuff than I do :) I guess it won't be possible for you to maybe supply a sample file? (I understand if it's private material)

Comment: Not sure I want to share the originals, but I should be able to re-create a corrupted file with the same process. I'll update about the ffmpeg suggestion this weekend.

Comment: Yup. Same here :( I have QuickTime videos from 2000 with data forks but no resource fork.

I dumped the raw file in hex and it begins: `....mdat....mjpg`, which signify:

1. [MDAT](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=QuickTime_container#mdat) is a Media Data atom in the QT format

2. the video is compressed using the [Motion JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) codec.

Hoping I can somehow wrap the file in an empty "shell" MOV to make it play?

Uploaded [sample file](http://public.jm3.net/flix/greenvectors), @slhck, in case you know how to make these files playable again.